# div container with variable height iframe and div box not expanding properly

Tags: css, variables, html, height

I am making a basic template for a website. It has div containers of 1 header, a main menu listed horizontally below the header, the main content which is a google maps iframe (variable width) and a sidebar (absolute width, floated right) and a footer.

I am having some trouble with the height of the main content. I would like the iframe and the sidebar to have equal height whilst fitting to the page and leaving a margin for the footer but the main content always sets itself to min-height rather than stretching to the page.

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header"><img src="images/logo.png" width="360" height="127" /> </div><!--header-->

      <div id="menu">
         <ul><li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="network.html">Network</a></li>
         <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
         <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li></ul>
      </div><!--mrnu-->

      <div id="content">
         <div id="sidebar">
         Sidebar
         </div><!--sidebar-->

      <div id="main">
         <iframe id="map" width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=52.988337,3.120117&amp;num=1&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=6&amp;ll=51.206883,7.756348&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
      </div><!--main-->

      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div><!--content-->

      <div class="push"></div><!--push-->

      <div id="footer" class="footer">
      </div><!--footer-->
   </div><!--wrapper-->
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 75.00%; 
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/bg.png);
}
a{
    color: #090; 
    text-decoration:none; 
}
a:focus, a:hover, a:active { 
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden
}
* {
   margin: 0;
}
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
/* div tags */

#wrapper    {
   width: auto;
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto -100px;
}
#header { 
   position: relative;
   width: auto; 
   height: auto; 
   background-color: #090; 
}

#menu { 
   width: auto; 
   height: auto; 
   border: 2px solid #000; 
   font-size: 18px; 
}

#menu ul { 
   padding: 0px; 
   margin: 0px; 
   text-align: center; 
}

#menu li { 
   display: inline; 
   padding: 50px; 
}

#content    {
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
}

#main   {
   width: auto;
   margin-right: 125px;
}
#map    {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

#sidebar    {
   width: 125px;
   height: auto;
   float: right;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #FC0;
}

#footer {
   width: auto;
   height: 125px;
   background-color:#CC0;

}
/* classes */

.clear  {
   clear: both;
}

.footer .push   {
   height:125px;
}
```

**Note:** There may be 1 or 2 unused lines of code that I haven't spotted when I've been playing around with it so if anything seems out of place then it probably is.

I have seen solutions to this problem with fixed width containers, but I think the problem lies in my use of the float function. I have read that positioning needs to be absolute for this to work properly, however using float is the only way I have been able to find that allows the map to fill the space using variable width.

It could be something as simple as being incompatible with the browsers I am testing on but I'm not sure.

Thanks in advance and sorry if this post is a bit messy. I'm sure I will learn to keep clean soon enough ;D

Comment: Here is a screenshot of my problem.

http://i1326.photobucket.com/albums/u652/DjDaihatsu/screenshot_zpsacdba33f.png

I don't want all that space at the bottom.

Comment: I have also checked on chrome and ie and both return the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these style changes-:

```
#map    {
   width: 100%;
//   height: auto;
}

#content    {
   width: auto;
   //height: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Setting #content to height:auto pushes the #footer div to meet the #content div.

and in `<iframe>` set height to 100% (or 80% to show footer). It still leaves the issue of the map div now pushing the footer to below screen height. To deal with that, possibly set an absolute height for the iframe, or use an alternative to iframe.

Comment: Thank you suspectus. That seems to have done it, but yes now I can't see the footer. What do you suggest as an alternative? I was just looking at Ajax, as suggested by google, but I'm not exactly sure how to implement it.

Comment: Have a look at the google maps javascript API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial. Javascript usage is required. AJAX maybe required depending on what the site needs to do. I don't think AJAX is required to use the google maps javascript API.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling with all this for a while and I have decided that I'm going to use an API but build the skin for it with filters in actionscript as I can't find a map plugin that suits my needs.

I would also ideally use the winkel tripel projection as the projection that google uses isn't actually to a real-world scale but I haven't found an API that supports this yet.